# Node.js read ECONNRESET

Tags: node.js, express, post, econnreset

I am using Express.js for my application and I get the error when making a post request to adobe analytics API.

I tried to add `server.timeout` but it doesn't fix it...

This is the error message:

> Error: read ECONNRESET
>       at exports._errnoException (util.js:1028:11)
>       at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:572:26) code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read'

This is the code that fails:

```
  pullClassifications(req) {
    const dfd = q.defer();
    const { username, password, payload } = req;
    const data = wsse({username: username, password: password});
    const wsseHeaders = {'X-WSSE': data.toString({ nonceBase64: true })};
    const options = {
      'method': 'post',
      'headers': wsseHeaders,
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'body': payload,
      'json': true,
      'url': 'https://api.omniture.com/admin/1.4/rest/?method=ReportSuite.GetClassifications'
    }

    request(options, function(err, response, body) {
      if(response.statusCode == 200) {
        dfd.resolve(body);
      } else {
        dfd.reject({statusCode: response.statusCode, body: body});
      }
    })
    return dfd.promise;
  }
```

Update:
I tried to post the same request using Postman and it works, returning the response in 630000 ms.

What is the cause of this error and is there any way to fix it?

Comment: The error might be unrelated to Node.js/https module. I suggest you to try that outside of Node.js (ex. with curl or something like Postman)

Comment: @fardjad I tried with Postman and it works. Total time is 630000ms

Comment: This seems like a problem on the API side

Comment: @RenatoGama but why it works using Postman?

Comment: Same problem here. Works with postman, but doesn't work on my backend.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `timeout` option in request? Why are you using Q promise library when you could do it using native promises? Old NodeJs version?

https://github.com/request/request#timeouts

```
    const options = {
      'timeout': 120 * 60 * 1000 //(120 seconds)
      'method': 'post',
      'headers': wsseHeaders,
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'body': payload,
      'json': true,
      'url': 'https://api.omniture.com/admin/1.4/rest/?method=ReportSuite.GetClassifications'
    }

    request(options, function(err, response, body) {...});
```

Comment: I tried to add the `timeout` option to request and still not working. I'm not using an old NodeJs version, just the whole project uses Q promise.

Comment: Doing `timeout: 0` would disable the request timeout?